# Radzen Blazor DropDown on dynamic data from external API

Tags: drop-down-menu, blazor, blazor-webassembly, radzen

I'm getting data from an external API and the code looks like this (this part is fine):

```
@code {
    IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> data;
    int count;
    bool isLoading;

    async Task LoadData(LoadDataArgs args)
    {
        isLoading = true;
        var uri = new Uri("https://services.radzen.com/odata/Northwind/Employees")
            .GetODataUri(filter: args.Filter, top: args.Top, skip: args.Skip, orderby: args.OrderBy, count: true);

        var response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri));

        var result = await response.ReadAsync<ODataServiceResult<IDictionary<string, object>>>();

        data = result.Value.AsODataEnumerable();
        count = result.Count;
        isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

On the dropdown menu I want to display the EmployeeID, but cannot access it (the Data="@data.Employee.ID" is incorrect and not sure what to put in there to make it work).

```
<RadzenDropDown Data="@data.EmployeeID" TextProperty="EmployeeID" ValueProperty="EmployeeID" Name="Dropdown1" TValue="string">
            </RadzenDropDown>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `Data` field is not an object of a class with a `EmployeeId` field inside. It is a dictionary, with a key of type "string", and value of type object. Is the "key" (string) your "emmployeeId" ?

Comment: I am a bit confused: `Data` is probably (I don't know Radzen) supposed to contain a collection (ex: IEnumerable, List, Dictionary...), which means you cannot put `@data.EmployeeID` in this field. However, I don't understand how you will use `data` in your case. `data` is basically a list of dictionaries, which means you will have one entry in your drop down list for each dictionary inside data and not every element inside your dictionaries.

Comment: The same requirement here, tried converting Dictionary<string,object> to ExpandoOjbect (dynamic) but didn't help. Now I'm trying to override the behaviour of the component. Let's stay connected :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Data Property is:

```
 IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> data;
```

It should be:

```
IEnumerable<Employee>data;
```

So then you can acess to Employee class properties.

```
<RadzenDropDown Data="@data.EmployeeID" TextProperty="EmployeeID" ValueProperty="EmployeeID" Name="Dropdown1" TValue="Employee">
            </RadzenDropDown>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take this tutrial, you'll find the whole class in the end of the article
   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/#fromHistory
2. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly` must be changed to `AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly` (in order to work with .net core and .net 5+)
3. Example Code of the page. You'll loop on your Dictionary to t.GetProperty("UserID").SetValue(...

   `@code
        {
            string value { get; set; }
            List data = new();
            protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
            {
                MyClassBuilder MCB = new MyClassBuilder ("ClsUser");
                var myclass = MCB.CreateObject(new string[4] { "UserID", "Username", "Birthday", "Location" }, new Type[4] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(DateTime), typeof(string) });
                Type t = myclass.GetType();
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                t.GetProperty("UserID").SetValue(obj, "34", null);
                        t.GetProperty("Username").SetValue(obj, "Albert", null);
                        t.GetProperty("Birthday").SetValue(obj, new DateTime(1976, 3, 14), null);
                        t.GetProperty("Location").SetValue(obj, "KRK", null);
                data.Add(obj);
        }
    }`